# Regex in ARGV. Perl

Tags: regex, perl

If i put variable instead of regexp in code, program didn't find pattern, why?

**Not working:**

```
my $regex = $ARGV[0];
print $file "$1\n" if $_ =~ /(\b\$regex\b)/;
```

**Works:**

```
print $file "$1\n" if $_ =~ /(\b\w{3}\b)/;
```

Also if i input as argument to program smth like W{3,2}, the 2 counts as the second argument. How to avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a shell question.  Enclose your parameter in quotes:

```
perl yourscript.pl '\w{3}'
```

Then remove the escaping in your code so the `$regex` variable can be interpolated:

```
my $regex = $ARGV[0];
print $file "$1\n" if $_ =~ /(\b$regex\b)/;   # Removed \ before $regex
```